# Filter dates where difftime is within 5 days

Tags: r, dataframe, datediff

my dataframe looks like this

```
    df <- read.table(text="
                 id       date
    1            1        2016-12-01 
    2            2        2017-01-02 
    3            4        2017-01-02 
    4            6        2017-01-02 
    5            7        2017-01-02 
    6            9        2017-01-02
    7            10       2017-08-02
", header=TRUE)
```

What I need is to filter dates, where difftime is equal or less than five days. In example above it should be firtered ids between 2-9

Comment: Does *difftime is equal or less than five days* mean the difference between two consecutive rows?

Comment: Not just consecutive, each row where difference is less than five. In my example 2017-01-02 and 2017-01-02

Comment: See if this does it: `inx <- c(difftime(df$date[-nrow(df)], df$date[-1], units = "days"), Inf);df[abs(inx) <= 5, ]`. But you must first do `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradasor you could use `diff.difftime(df$date, unit = 'days')`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- ymd(df$date)

df$flag <- ifelse(difftime(lead(df$date), df$date, units = c("days")) >=5,1,0)

df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

This might be the answer you are looking for.